# MVC ASP Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I know there are a few posts on this matter, but I couldn't get any option working. I'm going nuts.
I'm pretty new in MVC and JavaScript. I get the following error in my console:

> FamilyStudentJS.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
>           at HTMLDocument. (FamilyStudentJS.js:20)
>           at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
>           at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
>           at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

I tried many references. Still, my C# function isn't launched. When I manually run it, it works fine.

My HTML code:

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamilyNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10" id="fs">
            <label> <input type="checkbox" id="FamilyCheckBox"> Family attached? </label>
        <div id="familysection" style="display:none" >
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="FamilyIDTextBox" />
            </span>
        </div>
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FamilyNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FamilyCheckBox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Students/GetSearchValue",
                type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.startfrom };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        messages: { noResults: "", results: "" }
    });
})
```

C#:

```cs
public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string search)
{
    var temp = new FamilyViewModel();

    EzappContext db = new EzappContext();
    List<Family> allsearch = db.Families.Where(x => x.FamilyName.Contains(search)).Select(x => new Family
    {
        FamilyName = x.FamilyName,
        FamilyNum = x.FamilyNum
    }).ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = allsearch, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: are you using `jquery ui autocomplete`?

Comment: yes.those are my references
 <script src="~/Scripts/FamilyStudentJS.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: have you added your references for jquery and javascript before your javascript code?

Comment: yes. when I do that, I get no error on the console and no action for autocomplete or the break point at the start of the c# code

Comment: change order of script files as jquery , jqueryUI and then FamilyStudent.js an check if that helps.

Comment: I just ran it. still not working :
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/FamilyStudentJS.js"></script>

Comment: Use an autocomplete on a checkbox makes no sense. I assume you want `$("#FamilyIDTextBox").autocomplete(` (not `FamilyIDTextBox`), but then you have it in a hidden element so its not really clear what your trying to do

Comment: this is an optional added attribute. I have checkbox above the textbox that if the user click I have JS function to show it. once I show it I would like to use autocomplete. not sure what you meant by (not FamilyIDTextBox).
is there anything wrong with the textbox approach?

Comment: Sorry, that should of read _not `FamilyCheckBox`_. Your attaching the autocomplete to an element with `id="FamilyCheckBox"`, which is a checkbox (the textbox which is what you want to attach it to, has `id="FamilyIDTextBox"`)

Comment: thank you!! it finally launched my c# function. but my string is empty. what am I doing wrong here with passing the parameter to my function?

Comment: Because your passing a value named `term`, so you method parameter needs to match - `public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string term)`